# Why does Windows *require* User Verification when registering WebAuthn?

Tags: windows, authentication, usability, fido2, webauthn

During WebAuthn registration in Windows, why does Windows **require** User Verification, even when the Relying Party does not specify the User Verification requirement, or specifies it as `preferred`? Is it possible to change OS settings in order to allow a user to skip User Verification when it is not `required`?

As of Jan. 2023, when using a Windows browser to register a WebAuthn-compatible roaming authenticator (e.g. YubiKey) to a service that does not explicitly set the [User Verification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#user-verification) value to [`discouraged`](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#enum-userVerificationRequirement) (i.e. User Verification is either `preferred` or simply not set), Windows will **require** the user to either:

A) register a User Verification method (such as a FIDO2 PIN), if one has *not already* been set

-OR-

B) authenticate using the User Verification method, if one has *already* been set

...in order to allow the WebAuthn registration to proceed.

This is even true when the Relying Party does not require that User Verification should/must be used during authentication, such that User Verification will be required to *register* the WebAuthn device, but then never requested when the device is actually *used* to authenticate.

It is unclear to me whether Windows has always used this logic, or if it has recently been introduced (I'd love to know). This seems **incredibly hostile** to end-users who are [not aware of what is happening](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402836718866-Understanding-YubiKey-PINs) or how to properly manage something like a FIDO2 PIN (read: nearly everyone).

I understand the importance of utilizing User Verification when WebAuthn is used as a "passwordless" auth method. However, WebAuthn is not used in **only** "passwordless" scenarios, and is arguably more commonly used similar to U2F as a form of multi-factor authentication *in addition to* a password. Given this, I am simply dumbfounded (and frankly, a bit enraged) by Window's behavior and the confusion it causes.

Comment: Doesn't presenting your fingerprint to your YubiKey count as User Verification?

Comment: @Spiff For touch-activated (non-biometric) security keys (e.g. YubiKey 5 series), presenting the *touch* action is considered User *Presence* (someone is actually there) rather than User *Verification* (the user is who they claim to be). I believe that for biometric-enabled YubiKeys (e.g. YubiKey Bio series), the *fingerprint validation* is used as User Verification instead of a FIDO2 PIN, although I have not tested this myself.